# Saving and loading an object in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to save an object that I have in my program (this object stores data) to the hard drive so i can load it next time the program starts

I have tried using serialization and xml file output but I cant seem to get this working since the data I have is not of the 'string' object type.

I considered using file open/put/get but MSDN recommends against this since it is much more inefficient than serialization.

Any simple load/save functions that will accomplish my goal?

Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: What seems to be the problem with serialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to convert the object to binary data before serialization.

For others, here are my functions

```
'Imports
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

'Functions
Public Function Load()
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(mstrSaveFile) Then
        Dim fs As Stream = New FileStream(mstrSaveFile, FileMode.Open)
        Dim bf As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()
        mstrData = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), CType(mstrData))
        fs.Close()
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Public Function Save()
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(mstrSaveFile) = True Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(mstrSaveFile)
    End If
    Dim fs As Stream = New FileStream(mstrSaveFile, FileMode.Create)
    Dim bf As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()
    bf.Serialize(fs, mstrData)
    fs.Close()
    Return True
End Function
```